# why we should use create and copytruncate together?

Tags: logrotate

[The Geek Stuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/) has an example about `logrotate`. `copytruncate` will copy and truncate the original log file.

Then why we should use `create`? The original log file has not been removed.

```
/tmp/output.log {
  size 1k
  copytruncate
  create
  compress
  compresscmd /bin/bzip2
  compressext .bz2
  rotate 4
  maxage 100
}
```

Another question is what is the use of `maxage 100`? The `rotate 4` directive will delete old log files after 4 rotation.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't make sense and `man logrotate` even says so: "*copytruncate*: [...] When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place."

Comment: `maxage 100` will delete rotated files when they become over 100 days old and the current file is rotated; even when fewer than `4` rotated files exist.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

That is probably a mistake, it is found only in one example on that tutorial. All other examples have `copytruncate` without the `create` option. Also `logrotate` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) states that **It will be actually ignored**:

> `copytruncate`
>
> Truncate  the  original log file to zero size in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one.  It can be used when some program cannot be told  to  close
>                 its  logfile  and  thus might continue writing (appending) to the previous log file forever.  Note that
>                 there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might
>                 be lost.  When this option is used, the create option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in
>                 place.

---

Regarding `maxage`, I think it can be useful for example for logfiles which can be empty for few rotation periods (days/weeks/months) — if you use `notifempty`, empty logfile will not be rotated, so you can have too old rotated files still in place.

Comment: Please help me to get an answer to my question also https://serverfault.com/questions/997734/log-rotation-not-working-properly

Comment: I just noticed that the Tomcat package for Ubuntu (6/14 & 8/18) bundles a logrotate conf that includes both `copytruncate` and `create ...`. Baffling!